# what do javascript event listeners compile to in assembly language

Tags: javascript, performance, assembly, web

I'm looking at the performance of javascript event listeners and trying to understand them better. My question is what does an event listener look like in assembly language, EX what does it compile to? Likewise, when events fire in javascript, what is the set of assembly code instructions that execute. Not necessarily looking for exact x_86 code, but an overview would be nice, and I can't seem to find any online.

Comment: This is going to depend on the JavaScript engine used.  You might have to dig into the source for V8 or another engine.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to see how your question makes a lot of sense for several reasons.  Let me explain a bit how this works and then maybe you'll see why there isn't a direct answer to your question.

First, javascript is an interpreted language.  It is parsed into it's own byte codes and then the byte codes are executed by an interpreter.  In a way, you could say that it has it's own instruction set rather than using the CPU instruction set.  There are various levels of byte code optimization to make things as fast as possible and exactly how that is done varies by the implementation.  But, suffice it to say that javascript is not fully compiled into all x86 assembly instructions like C or C++ would be.  So, there is no exact set of x86 instructions that uniquely corresponds to a given set of javascript.

Second, there are multiple layers in the system involved here.  At the lowest level, there is the OS, it's drivers and it's event sub-system that creates these events such as mouseDown or keyDown.  That code will likely be written in C/C++ and has been reduced to assembly language.  One level up, is the browser event system that sits on top of the OS.  This is what interfaces with the OS system and makes the controls in a web page actually work and capture actual events.  Then, one level up further is the javascript interface which allows a javascript script to register an event handler that will get called when an event occurs.

We can explain how this works conceptually, but not at the x86 assembly instruction level.  Conceptually:

1. JS code calls `elem.addEventListener("click", fn);`
2. This code calls the `addEventListener` method on the native object `elem`.
3. Since addEventListener is probably not implemented in javascript (more likely in the "C/C++" browser implementation), the code goes through an interface layer where the arguments are packaged into the right form and a C/C++ function/method is called.
4. This method maintains a list of event handlers for each object.  For performance reasons, that list is probably organized by event type.  The event type and JS function to call is stored in a list that is associated with a specific DOM element.
5. When an event occurs for a specific DOM element, that event is detected in the C/C++ engine in the browser.  That engine then checks the event handling lists for that DOM object to see if there are any event handlers for this DOM object that are interested in this specific event.  If there is, then it sets up to call that event handler.
6. The code to call the handler again has to go through an interface layer from C/C++ back to the javascript world.  The event data structure is built and populated and then the event handler is called with all the right arguments.
7. When the event handler returns, any other event handlers on the same DOM object for the same event are also called.
8. If this is an event that propagates and event propagation hasn't been stopped by any of the event handlers, then the event propagates up through the parents, again looking for matching event handlers to call.
9. Depending upon the type of event, if there is a default behavior for that event (such as a click of a link) and the default behavior was not prevented, then the default action is executed (default behavior might be before propagation).

FYI, if you wanted to see the browser's C/C++ code for dealing with event handling, you could always go look at the webkit or Firefox source code as they are both open source.  But, that's only part of the mechanism as other parts of the system and browser and JS interpreter are involved.

A lot of the webkit event handling code can be found here: https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/tree/e7207313fed4b7a2140c39f65d45e0f441731735/Source/WebCore/dom